# Netsuite - Purchase order for Assembly/Bill of Materials

Tags: netsuite

By default, NetSuite does not allow you to create purchase orders for Assembly/Bill of Material items. In the system settings, you are able to select "Allow Purchase of Assembly" to create a purchase orders for assembly items.

However, after receiving the assembly item into inventory and fulfilling an order, NetSuite still commits the components in the Bill of Materials. And since we purchased the assembly and not the inventory items that make up the assembly, our inventory item quantity goes to negative which is no good.

Is there a way for NetSuite to automatically assign inventory to the Bill of Materials that make up the Assembly when creating a purchase order for that assembly? Or is there a way where NetSuite does not commit inventory items when the assembly was purchased through a PO?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, You can close the work order which should Un commit the components. Then use reallocate items. This should address the issue.

This would not be automated

Comment: Thank you for your response - Would I be able to reallocate inventory items from an Assembly build that was added through a purchase order?

Comment: Try it. Create a test order of an assembly item and then experiment.

Answer (score 0):

After receiving the assembly item (PO --> Item Receipt), do an **assembly unbuild** to put the member components into inventory.  Then your work order will function as normal.

The steps as NetSuite will see it.

1. Item Receipt adds one of the assembly to inventory. (complete
   assembly, not members)
2. Assembly unbuild removes the assembly from inventory and returns the member        items to inventory.
3. Work order removes member items and adds assembly back into inventory.
4. Finally the Item Fulfillment takes the assembly out of inventory.